# Passing 2-d array by reference only passing first dimension back

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, pass-by-reference, c-strings

So for an assignment I have to make a program that parses a string into words, making use of pass by reference to save the words to an array. I've almost completed the assignment, except when I try to print the results I find that only the first letter of each word got passed back out of the parsing function, and all other values of the array return null.

the array that's being passed is defined as `char *tokenArray[MAXSTRING];`

it is being passed to the array `char **args[]`. I know from various test prints that args is getting each complete word, it's just that for some reason only the first letter of each winds up in tokenArray.

the line where it's supposed to be being passed by reference is this:

```
tokenResult = makearg(strInput, &tokenArray);

corresponding to the function definition:

int makearg(char s[], char **args[])
```

If you need more information please dont hesititate to let me know. Im honestly just confused as hell right now and don't even really know what other sections of my code might be useful here.

EDIT: As requested, here's the complete program. Be warned, it's a lot messier than I'd like it to be for a variety of reasons

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int MAXSTRING = 255;

int makearg(char s[], char **args[]);

int main()
{
   char *tokenArray[MAXSTRING];
   char strInput[MAXSTRING];
   int tokenResult;
   int i = 0;
   int j = 0;

   printf("Input String to be Parsed: ");
   scanf("%[^\n]%*c", strInput);

   tokenResult = makearg(strInput, &tokenArray);

   printf("argc: %d\n", tokenResult);
   for (i = 0; i < tokenResult; i++)
   {
      printf("arg(%d): %s\n", i, (tokenArray[i][1])); //specifically tries to print the second character to make sure not just the 1st one got passed. right now this only returns null
   }
}

int makearg(char s[], char **args[])
{
   int numTokens = 0;
   int lastSpace = 0;
   int i = 0;
   int j = 0;
   int fakeI;
   char token[MAXSTRING];
   int subFromPos = 0;
   int firstToken = 1;

   *args = NULL;
   while ((s[i] != '\n') && (s[i] != '\0') && (s[i] != '\r'))
   {
      fakeI = i;
      if ((s[i + 1] == '\n') || (s[i + 1] == '\0'))
      {
         fakeI = i + 1;
      }

      token[i - lastSpace - subFromPos] = s[i];

      if ((s[fakeI] == ' ') || (s[fakeI] == '\n') || (s[fakeI] == '\0') || (s[fakeI] == '\r')) //checks for end of word
      {
         if (firstToken == 1)
         {
            token[fakeI - lastSpace] = '\0'; //appends \0 to end of word
            firstToken = 0;
         } else if (firstToken == 0){
            token[i - lastSpace] = '\0'; //appends \0 to end of word
         }
         *args = realloc(*args, (numTokens + 1)); //resizes the first dimension of args
         args[numTokens] = realloc(args[numTokens], (fakeI - lastSpace + 1)*(sizeof(char))); //resizes the second dimension of args
         printf("token: %s\n", token); //tests to make sure the token was isolated correctly
         while (token[j] != '\0')
         {
            args[numTokens][j] = token[j]; //writes token to args, character by character
            j++;
         }
         j = 0;
         printf("Saved Token: %c\n", args[numTokens][2]); //checks the third character of the word to make sure not just the 1st one got written
         numTokens++;
         lastSpace = fakeI;
         subFromPos = 1;
      }
      i++;
   }
   return numTokens;
}
```

EDIT 2: Here's the expected input and expected output for the program as it is currently written

```
Input String to be Parsed: hello my friend
 
argc: 3 //the total number of tokens in the array
arg(0): l //the third character of the 1st token
arg(1): (null) //third character of 2nd token ("my" only has 2 hence null) arg(2): i
```

I should also confess, I have been getting some compiler warnings, but I can't find a way to get rid of them that doesn't make the program crash due to a segmentation fault. They are as follows:

> 270a1.c: In function ‘main’:
> 270a1.c:20:4: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘makearg’ from
> incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
> tokenResult = makearg(strInput, &tokenArray);

> 270a1.c:7:5: note: expected ‘char ***’ but argument is of type ‘char *
> (*)[(sizetype)(MAXSTRING)]’  int makearg(char s[], char **args[]);

> 270a1.c: In function ‘makearg’: 270a1.c:68:32: warning: assignment
> makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
> args[numTokens][j] = token[j];

Comment: If you don't know what information would be required, I suggest you post your whole program.  Or even better, strip it right back to the minimum amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem, and post that.  The issue we encounter on Stack Overflow way too often is someone is struggling to grasp what's happening, takes a wild guess at the problem, leaves out _all_ the important code and then tries to describe the program in English based on their understanding of how it works.  There's a massive flaw in that thinking: You don't know what you don't know.

Comment: TLDR; we don't know if the issue is in your function, or how you're calling it, or how you're storing your data, or how you're using the results.  And you haven't shown any of those things, with the exception of the invocation where you variables whose type and history we cannot know.

Comment: @paddy In that case I'll have to post the whole program, since I'm pretty sure the whole thing is necessary to easily replicate the precise scenario. I was hoping to avoid that though, since recently people have gotten frustrated with me for posting too much code

Comment: Yeah, it's frustrating either way.  The thing the needs to be taught to beginners is how to systematically investigate a problem, isolate it and work backwards to the root cause.  This is called debugging.  Apparently this lifelong skill is not learned until far too late these days, and I've never seen it adequately taught.  Supplementing that is the ability to present all the important information about an issue to someone who has the expertise to help.

Comment: @IanFinnigan try to make a [mcve]. This is a current technique for finding problems, not only form posting questions on stackoverflow. You even might find the problem yourself in the process.

Comment: @Jabberwocky In this case I don't think there's much I can do on that front since the whole program is just for generating the output that I've been having trouble with. In other words, it's already as minimal as I can make it, the best i can do is add a few more comments to improve readability

Comment: @IanFinnigan thanks for posting your code. It is not that big after all.

Comment: @IanFinnigan didn't you get compiler warnings (which are actually errors in this case)? And what is the program supposed to do? Please [edit] and show a simple example of input and expected output.

Comment: Well, among the many things wrong, `(numTokens + 1)` certainly isn't the right byte count to pass to that realloc for `*args = realloc(*args, (numTokens + 1));`

Comment: It's indeed quite a mess and hard to follow what looks like it's supposed to be a simple tokenizer that splits words separated by whitespace.  Apart from the type error in the second argument, you haven't quite made up your mind whether to allocate a dynamic-sized or a fixed-size array of strings.  Either way, the calls to `realloc` are bogus because the pointer being reallocated is uninitialized.  Even fixing these things and making it operate on a fixed-size array of pointers, the program crashes unless I comment out all the stuff that modifies args and then make the function return 0.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I've made the edits you requested

Comment: @paddy Is there any way at all for me to get this to work? I'm fine with tearing everything out and starting over if that's what it takes

Comment: I'm also deftly curious what all the newline junk is all about in `makearg`. The `scanf` from `main` explicitly *stops* reading on encounter of a newline, so there shouldn't even be any. Regardless, is it *really* you intent to declare `args` in `main` to ba an array of 255 pointer to pointer to char ? isn't the goal here to get a dynamic array of dynamic length strings? Or at least a dynamic array of fixed-length strings? I think this is recoverable, but you need to *stop coding* until you have a formal plan. It will only get worse with that.

Comment: Haha well yeah actually not only was the function broken, but the final output was too.  So I removed stuff from your function, then went "screw it, I'll rewrite this".  Wrote a function and boom it crashed.  Fixed your output, and then both versions work.

Comment: @paddy What was wrong with the output?

Comment: It was probably a combination of how much divination was required to fix the numerous issues in this program.  Guessing one intent caused issues elsewhere.  Basically you handed us a program that doesn't even compile.  Here is the scratch program I was working with, fixing your old function _more or less_ (it still has off-by-one kinds of errors due to the obfuscated index calculations).  Made it work with dynamic-sized array.  It includes the version that I knocked up, which you should agree is much easier to follow.  https://godbolt.org/z/E5Paeh9Kn

Comment: @paddy That looks like pretty much what [I thought as well](https://godbolt.org/z/4P9s8E3ha).

Comment: Yours is _way_ more robust than mine... I did no failure tests to keep it simple.  OP should follow your example ;)

Comment: @paddy Thanks for your help, you're an absolute lifesaver

Comment: @WhozCraig You're also an absolute lifesaver. You've both given me a lot of advice I'll be sure to use going forward

Comment: You're welcome.  To avoid problems like this in future, it's highly recommended to write code in short bursts and test often.  Try to build up bits that you know work, so you can expand on those.  As you grow more proficient at writing working code, testing it and debugging issues, you'll be able to make more changes between tests.